# Azure AD Workbook: export parameter under the advances setting is not working for pie chart

Tags: azure, azure-monitor-workbooks

We have created workbooks under the Azure AD. Trying to use the export parameter under the Advances setting of KQL to load the parameter related data on click.
It is working perfectly fine when I am choosing the grid visualization instead of pie.

Our requirement is to have the pie chart and when hovering on it, should load the related data in another grid view.

Is this limitation of a workbook or something I am missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can also export selections from charts, but the available fields are *not* the names of the columns like in a grid.  there's no way to have *hover* export selections though.

from [the github docs](https://github.com/microsoft/Application-Insights-Workbooks/blob/master/Documentation/Interactivity.md#interactivity-with-multiple-selections-in-grids-and-charts) (emphasis added):

> Note: you can leave the Field to export setting empty in the export settings. If you do, all available fields in the data will be exported as a stringified JSON object of key:value pairs. For grids and tiles, this will be all of the fields in the grid. **For charts, the available fields will be x, y, series, label (depending on the type of chart).**

I'm working on getting this updated in our [public azure docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/workbooks-interactive#interactivity-with-multiple-selections-in-grids-and-charts), which for some reason only have 1 one of the three "note" items in that section.

Comment: If I have a pie chart with multiple selections, is it possible to parse_json in the KQL to get the individual selections or is this not supported?

Comment: yes, you could use `parse_json`, or `dynamic` in queries to parse apart the json if you need to.  you can also use json path formatting of the params to pick out individual fields from a parameter as well. see: https://github.com/microsoft/Application-Insights-Workbooks/blob/master/Documentation/Parameters/Parameters.md#formatting-parameters-using-jsonpath